# Intermittent latency / lag in games and video conferencing (every 30 [33] seconds)

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, performance, latency, geolocation

After using a decent tier laptop (Lenovo Yoga Slim, AMD Ryzen™ 7 4700U CPU, 16 GB LPDDR4x RAM, 512 GB M.2 PCIe NVMe SSD) for a couple of months my wife started to get latency spikes in League of Legends, usually she sits around 35ms in ping, but suddenly it would spike at 150ms.

Since this is her work computer this became a big issue when the same happened in her video conferencing meetings as well.

I tried finding out what it was but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to turn Windows 10 share location off. I turned location off and the latency issues was gone. Instructions here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-location-service-and-privacy-3a8eee0a-5b0b-dc07-eede-2a5ca1c49088#WindowsVersion=Windows_10

I could not figure this out so I installed Wireshark and started analyzing packages. After 2 hours closing programs and trying figure out what package that was causing this, I could not find anything.

After setting up ping to `google.com` (`ping google.com -t`) we figured out that the latency spikes were in 33 seconds intervals.

Searching for this I finally I found a post, can't find it now unfortunately, that had a similar issue.

My guess is that when sharing location Windows scans for surrounding networks to triangulate and this causes lag.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).